# Why redirect command changes POST method to GET?

Tags: flask

I use the following code:

```
25   @app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
26   def index():
27    if request.method == "POST":
28
29        # TODO: Add the user's entry into the database
30
31        return redirect("/")
32
33    else:
34
35        # TODO: Display the entries in the database on index.html
36
37        return render_template("index.html", birthdays)
```

Does `redirect("/")` mean going back to line 25?

Why does this not create an infinite loop?

It seems like the form method will change to `GET` after running `redirect()`. Is this what is happening?

Comment: For each request, the server responds with a response consisting of a status code and its description, optional header parameters and any following data.
In this case, redirect means that a response with the status code 302 Found and a location header with URL is sent. The browser interprets this as a request to send a GET request to said URL. The forwarding is only valid for this call, so the original address will continue to be used for future calls.

Answer (score 0):

The Flask redirect function by default sends back a 302 response which is interpreted incorrectly as a location to GET. Use a different status code that carries your original HTTP request type such as 307.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#special_redirections